# Estimate the scale of the power series with Poisson pdf-like terms

Tags: probability, analysis, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, closed-form

Sorry to bother you, but I guess that this question is not appropriate for MO, so I repost it here hoping that someone could give me a clue.

I would like to have an estimate for the series
$$P(t) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty (e^{-t}\frac{t^k}{k!})^m,$$
where $e$ is the base of natural logarithm, $k!$ is the factorial of the integer $k$, $t$ represents the time and $t>0$, $m$ is a positive integer and $m>1$ (Obviously, $P(t)=1$ when $m=1$ since $P(t)$ is exactly the cdf of Poisson distribution with associated parameter $t$ in this case.).

I am interested in showing that the order of the scale could look something like 
$$P(t) = O(t^{-\alpha m}),\alpha > 0.$$

But I find it difficult for me to extend their method to the cases when $m>2$. 

 I also tried to calculate $P(t)$ in Mathematica and it gave me the result like
$$P(t) = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^\infty (e^{-t}\frac{t^k}{k!})^m = e^{-mt}\text{HypergeometricPFQ}[...,t^m]$$
It seems that the decreasing speed of $P(t)$ is much slower than that of $e^{-mt}$ as $t$ increases. But I could not find the closed-form bound for $P(t)$ when $m>2$ just like $O(1/\sqrt t)$ when $m=2$.

Does anyone know of a scale or a bound of $P(t)$ in the literature? Any comments and answers would be highly appreciated. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function you have, and this is also the closed form that Mathematica gave you, is related to the [hypergeometric function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedHypergeometricFunction.html),
$$ P(t) = e^{-m t}\,\,{}_0F_{m-1}(;1,1,\ldots,1; t^m). $$
To calculate its behaviour as $t\to\infty$, at least in this case, is relatively easy. In particular the DLMF [gives the formulas necessary](http://dlmf.nist.gov/16.11), 16.11.9 and 16.11.1-4.

The result is
$$ P(t) = \frac{1}{(2\pi)^{\frac{m-1}{2}}\sqrt{m}}\frac{1}{t^{\frac{m-1}{2}}} + O(t^{\frac{-1-m}{2}}). $$

You can also check this for small values of $m$ using Mathematica's function `Series`, which understands how to calculate asymptotic behaviour.

Comment: Great answer, it helps me give the exact order of $P(t)$. ($P(t) = O(t^{(1-m)/2})\text{  }t\to\infty$) Thanks a lot.